# Xamarin Android EditText - Required field error displaying when control not empty

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext

Creating a dynamic EditText and adding 'some text' will display the required field error message even though text has been added to the control...

```
//Create EditText
editText = new EditText((Activity)form);
editText.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.MyCustomTheme);
editText.Text = "Some Text";
editText.Error = Html.FromHtml("<font color='black'>Cannot be Empty</font>").ToString();
```

[Error is displayed even though text is in the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vQbK.png)

Comment: check my ans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have give condition for it to check if edittext is empty or not 
try this

```
editText = new EditText((Activity)form);
editText.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.MyCustomTheme);
editText.Text = "Some Text";
editText.TextChanged += (sender, e) => {

   if (TextUtils.IsEmpty((sender as EditText).Text))
    {
        editText.SetError("Text Can't be empty!", null);

    }
};
```

Comment: That solves the problem of displaying the error when the form is loaded. However I still need the error to appear if the value inside the Textbox is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
editText = new EditText((Activity)form);
editText.TextChanged += (sender, e) => {

       if (TextUtils.IsEmpty((sender as EditText).Text))
        {
            editText.SetError("Text Can't be empty!", null);

        }
};
```